# ¿Por qué la función float devuelve un dato de tipo int?

Tags: array, c

**¿Por qué la función MEDIA devuelve un valor de un tipo no asignado?**

Aunque calcula ''bien'' la media del total de los 20 elementos del vector, no imprime los decimales y no entiendo dónde está el error. Ya he probado a definir la suma como float también pero no hay diferencia.

*Ya no sé qué más escribir, ignoren esto por favor. Tengan un buen dia.*

```
#define MAX 20
void MOSTRAR (int datos[], int n);
int SUMA (int datos[], int n);
float MEDIA (int sumatorio);

int main () {
   
   puts ("Este programa almacenará 20 números en un array y calculará la suma y media con ellos.");
   
   int vector[MAX];
   for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
       printf("\nInserte el elemento %d: ", i+1);
       scanf("%d", &vector[i]);
   } 
   
   MOSTRAR (vector, MAX);
   
   int suma=SUMA(vector, MAX);
   double media=MEDIA(suma);
   printf ("\nEl resultado de sumar todos los elementos del vector es %d", suma);
   printf ("\nCuya media es %g", media);
  
    return 0;
}


void MOSTRAR (int datos[], int n) {
    puts("\nLos elementos almacenados en el vector según su posición son: ");
    for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
        printf("\nvector[%d]=%d", i+1, datos[i]);
    }
return;
}


int SUMA (int datos[], int n) {
    int suma=0;
    for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
        suma=suma+datos[i];
    }
    return suma;
}


float MEDIA (int sumatorio) {
    float media=sumatorio/20;
    return media;
}
```

Comment: `%d` es para numeros enteros. Si quieres que imprima decimales, tienes que usar `%f`. [Referencia](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

Answer (score 0):

El parámetro `sumatorio` es de tipo entero y el literal `20` también. Entonces se realiza una división de enteros (sin decimales).

Para que se produzca una división de números reales, al menos uno de los 2 operandos debe ser de tipo `float` o `double`.

Puedes hacerlo cambiando el tipo del parámetro a `float` o escribiendo 20 como un literal de tipo `float` (`20.0f`).

Por cierto, como el resultado de la división es de tipo `float`, no ganas nada almacenandolo en una variable `double`:

```
double media = MEDIA(suma);
```